# Why doesn't my absolutely-positioned element display the specified background-color?

Tags: html, css, css-position, background-color

I was tweaking the code from:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/applied-visual-design/create-a-more-complex-shape-using-css-and-html

```html
<style>
  .heart {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .a{
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<div class="a">
  <div class="heart">Hello</div>
</div>
```

1. The `.heart` class has a background-color `green`, but it is not working. I have checked by using inspect on the web page and it is definitely not being overwritten by any other CSS style.

   What is happening here? Browser used: Google Chrome
2. Also, can you explain to me what is the use of:

   ```
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   ```

altogether and how does it work.

Comment: your heart div has no height because the parent container only has an absolutely positioned element inside it and you told the child to be as wide and tall as the parent.  If you want the background to show, you must give the parent element some height or remove some child constraints.  The second part of your question means that the child element will cover the full width and height of it's parent element

Comment: If you want to learn more about CSS positioning, take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). The reason why your element is not getting the green background is because you're setting both `top` and `bottom` _and_ `left` and `right` to `0`. Try removing `bottom` and `right`.

Comment: Your first post looks pretty good it's look like you had followed our guide [ask]. I f not you may find ever more in it to improve it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position read the bit before the syntax heading - it will explain the second part of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set

```
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

So the top edge is 0 pixels from the top edge of the containing block, while the bottom edge is 0 pixels from the bottom edge of the containing block, and so on.

This can be quite useful when you are trying to completely cover an element with some other content… but that isn't the case here.

The containing block is the nearest ancestor which is *not* `position: static`, in this case that would be `<div class="a">`.

Now, that div has **no content** which is in normal flow (the only content it has is the heart div which is absolutely positioned, a feature which takes it out of normal flow).

Since it has no content, it gets a computed height of **zero**.

This means that the heart div (remember where its edges are aligned to) *also* has a height of zero.

This means there are no pixels for the background colour to be applied to (and the text is still rendered because it has `overflow: visible` by default).

---

It's hard to say what the right *solution* is here because it isn't clear *why* you are using absolute positioning in the first place.

Just not using positioning would solve it, as would doing anything that gives `a` some height (such as setting its `height` property or putting some other content (which *is* in normal flow) inside.

The tutorial you link to sets `top`, `bottom` **and** `height` which really doesn't make sense. (ditto for the horizontal equivalents). If the goal is to draw a heart, then using a tool *designed* to draw with would be a better approach then hacking CSS into doing it.

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>I <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" viewbox="0 0 645 585" id="svg2">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       d="M 297.29747,550.86823 C 283.52243,535.43191 249.1268,505.33855 220.86277,483.99412 C 137.11867,420.75228 125.72108,411.5999 91.719238,380.29088 C 29.03471,322.57071 2.413622,264.58086 2.5048478,185.95124 C 2.5493594,147.56739 5.1656152,132.77929 15.914734,110.15398 C 34.151433,71.768267 61.014996,43.244667 95.360052,25.799457 C 119.68545,13.443675 131.6827,7.9542046 172.30448,7.7296236 C 214.79777,7.4947896 223.74311,12.449347 248.73919,26.181459 C 279.1637,42.895777 310.47909,78.617167 316.95242,103.99205 L 320.95052,119.66445 L 330.81015,98.079942 C 386.52632,-23.892986 564.40851,-22.06811 626.31244,101.11153 C 645.95011,140.18758 648.10608,223.6247 630.69256,270.6244 C 607.97729,331.93377 565.31255,378.67493 466.68622,450.30098 C 402.0054,497.27462 328.80148,568.34684 323.70555,578.32901 C 317.79007,589.91654 323.42339,580.14491 297.29747,550.86823 z"
       id="path2417"
       style="fill:#ff0000" />
    <g
       transform="translate(129.28571,-64.285714)"
       id="g2221" />
  </g>
</svg> code
</p>
```

The above SVG is based on [this public domain image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Love_Heart_SVG.svg).

Comment: Isn't top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; being used to center the div using heart class.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is because you are using both values left, right and top, bottom in your CSS, and as explained in @Quentin answer since the parent has no height and width, this would always result in `heart` div to have `0px` height and `0px` width, the following code snippet solve this

```html
<style>
  .heart {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .a{
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<div class="a">
<div class="heart">Hello</div>
</div>
```

another way to solve it:

```css
.heart {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}
.a{
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="heart">Hello</div>
</div>
```

And another way here too:

```css
.heart {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: green;
  }
 
  .a{
    position:relative;
    width:40px;
    height: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="heart">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you changed Question?

Comment: @Ehsan not sure what you are talking about, what did I change?

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* the background color doesn't apply with all four directional properties applied.